# App not showing up in iTunes Connect iAd Network module

Tags: iphone, sdk, iad

The last two Apps I have submitted and have had released (they're both Ready for Sale and have been for a while) are not showing up in the iTunes Connect iAd network module.

Usually I'd get a notification saying an App is receiving Live Ads and I'd see the usual impressions / requests / revenue data, but with these two they're not even listed.

I've double checked that iAds are enabled for both in iTunes Connect (and can verify this as I'm getting test ads on my test device) and am completely baffled as to why they're not showing up?

(I know that if they don't get any Ads served I'd still see the Apps listed with zero impressions and such.)

Has anyone had a similar experience or can perhaps shed some light on it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with iAdSupport@apple.com and although they didn't elaborate on the cause of the issue, they were able to fix it from their side within 24 hours.

If anyone has a similar issue, I suggest contacting Apple via the e-mail address above.